# The formula for the differential of a vector-valued function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, differential-forms, tensors

If we have a vector, $\,U=U\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)$, in the coordinate axis $\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)$, then why does the following differential relation hold?

$$ dU= \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_1}\right)dx_1 + \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_2}\right)dx_2 + \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_3}\right)dx_3 $$

Help would be appreciated – I'd like to see the proof of why this holds in the vector case.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Differentials_in_several_variables), your expression for $\,dU\,$ is the definition of total derivative. So I guess one can say _"by definition"_.

Comment: Hi Vlad. Do you have a link please?

Comment: You can click on the word "Wikipedia" in my previous comment. Alternatively, here is the same link again: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Differentials_in_several_variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Differentials_in_several_variables)

Comment: Thanks Vlad. The page provides the case I've already seen, where U is instead a scalar function, rather than a vector. I was interested in the vector case, but I'm now starting to think that the individual three components of the vector could be treat as functions of three variables, but this feels quite a 'sloppy' way to do it.

Comment: I apologize I did not read your question carefully before commenting on it.

Comment: You can look upon the expression as a condensed notation. The relation holds for each of the Cartesian components of $U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a vector valued function $u:\>(\Omega\subset {\mathbb R}^n)\to{\mathbb R}^m$ and a point $p\in\Omega$  the differential of $u$ at $p$ is a linear map  $$du(p) :\quad T_p\to T_{u(p)}, \qquad X\mapsto du(p).X\ ,$$ which is defined by
$$u(p+X)-u(p)=du(p).X+o\bigl(|X|\bigr)\qquad(X\to0)\ .\tag{1}$$
Since $p$ will be fixed in the sequel I shall just write $du$ for this map. Particular such functions are the coordinate functions $$x_i:\quad x=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)\mapsto x_i=\langle x,e_i\rangle\qquad(1\leq i\leq n)\ .$$ For these one has
$$x_i(p+X)-x_i(p)=p_i+X_i-p_i=X_i\ ,$$
so that, trivially, 
$$dx_i(X)=X_i\qquad(1\leq i\leq n)\ .$$
Now
$$du.X=du.\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i e_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\  \ du.e_i=\sum_{i=1}^n du.e_i \ \ dx_i(X)\ .\tag{2}$$
It remains to find out what the $du.e_i$ are. Putting $X:=t\>e_i$ in $(1)$ we have
$$u(p+ t e_i)-u(p)=t\  du.e_i +o\bigl(|t|\bigr)\qquad (t\to0)\ ,$$
which is the same as
$$du.e_i=\lim_{t\to0}{u(p+ t e_i)-u(p)\over t}=:\left({\partial u\over\partial x_i}\right)_p\ .$$
Plugging this into $(2)$ we obtain
$$du.X=\sum_{i=1}^n \left({\partial u\over\partial x_i}\right)_p\ dx_i(X)\ ,$$
and since this is true for all $X\in T_p$ we may as well write
$$du=\sum_{i=1}^n \left({\partial u\over\partial x_i}\right)_p\ dx_i\ .$$
Note that  $\left({\partial u\over\partial x_i}\right)_p$ is a vector, namely the $i^{\rm th}$ column vector of the Jacobian matrix of $u$ at $p$.